# HowTo Fix java serialization vulnerability in JMX?

Tags: java, security, serialization, rmi, jmx

https://github.com/frohoff/ysoserial

Is a proof-of-concept tool for generating payloads that exploit unsafe Java object deserialization. It also works with JMX.

Is there any way to make JMX secure?
I also read https://tersesystems.com/2015/11/08/closing-the-open-door-of-java-object-serialization/. I dont understand how to use NotSoSerial in my project.

Comment: I'm not sure that you can embed NotSoSerial in your project. But you can use it as Java Agent when you start your application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run NotSoSerial by building the project from githhub, then taking the jar and running the JVM with the following arguments on the command line:

```
-javaagent:notsoserial.jar -Dnotsoserial.whitelist=empty.txt
```

as specified in https://github.com/kantega/notsoserial#whitelisting-mode

If you want to use JMX but don't want to use RMI (which uses Java Serialization) then look into jmxtrans or Jolokia and see how you can best lock the JSON messages being passed through there.